# Smoke (mist) not working for existing file

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm doing my first project in Blender. I started in 2.82 and am now using 2.90. I'm making a frost sword where I want a nitrogren mist to fall down from the blade's edge defined by a vertex group. I succeeded in that while modelling, but then I did some changes to the model, and now I can't get the mist to work again. Even if I add completely new simple object to the scene and do quick smoke and bake, nothing shows up. If I open a new blender file and do quick smoke, it shows up fine, so I assume some scene setting has been messed up. It's been driving me nuts for hours now, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

[Model file here.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QbfoyaJF6nWQp0IunXAexTEBXP-gCh_y?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

No one , Not the blender file , not the model , not the primitives , not the simulator **None of them is at fault**.When you make a simulation , you also bake it , and im sure you also did that , if you bake the simulation , what it does is that it records the simulations animation so that it doesn't have to do heavy calculation it does while making the simulation for the first time , so try rebaking and come back again

Comment: It's already baked, no smoke visible.

Comment: have you baked it again?

Comment: Yes, I have done so.

Comment: Please check what is your cache mode , replay or modular

Comment: Its Modular mode.

Comment: @NickW sorry , i dont know then

Comment: Otherwise, there's a link to the model file if you want to look around in that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was caching. I had a cache left over from the last attempt I made at a smoke simulation, and [according to the warning in this documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/baking.html), Blender doesn't like multiple caches.

So the solution was to Move the Blender file to a new folder and add the smoke effect there, then it ran perfectly. For some reason it wasn't enough to delete the old caches, I had to start over in a new folder.

Comment: Use "free all bakes" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!